# What are these two nerves running parallel to the spine called?

Tags: neuroscience, central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system, autonomic-nervous-system, cranial-nerves

I was looking for a human body nervous system, and often times i found a picture like the one below, where there are two nerves running parallel to the spinal column. I searched for it, but nothing came up.

Can anyone tell me what are the names to these two nerve column parallel to the spine and what are their functions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this closeup image, you can see there is more than one nerve on each side that is parallel to the spine.

[image]

Source: [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qswFb.jpg)

First, they are the right and left **[sympathetic trunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_trunk)** that run from the base of the skull to the coccyx.

[image]

Image source: [Earthslab.com](https://www.earthslab.com/anatomy/thoracic-sympathetic-trunks-course-relations-ganglia-and-its-branches/)

Additionally, they could be the right and left **[long thoracic nerve](https://www.orthobullets.com/anatomy/10135/long-thoracic-nerve),** which innervate the serratus anterior muscles in the chest wall. In your image they appear like running along the spine, but in reality they run vertically and laterally in the chest wall.

[image]

Source: [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/MR-neurography-(MRN)-of-the-long-thoracic-nerve%3A-of-Deshmukh-Fayad/57973dee50ab72340ebd232872dbb94121c201ed/figure/0)